# Update data by matching a Parent node - Firebase Database

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update my **password value**, I will input the username and search for a parent node that would match the username text to change the password.
[image]
Here's my code

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Changing Password");
            newPassword();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Change successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });//inside of onCreate method


private void newPassword(){

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userText.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input username.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(emailText.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(contactText.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input contact no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstText.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input first name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastText.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input last name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(retype.getText().toString().trim())){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input retype password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String username = userText.getText().toString().trim();
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(username.matches(ds.getKey())){
                    user.setPassword(password.getText().toString().trim());
                    ds.getRef().child(username).child("password").setValue(user.getPassword());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("User", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

My question is how to get to the node that I want to change its values, and every time I pressed the button, the password's value won't change.

Thanks for your help.

**EDITED**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);

    ...

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    db.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            username = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("username").getValue();
            address = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("address").getValue();
            contact = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("contact").getValue();
            email = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("email").getValue();
            first = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("first").getValue();
            last = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("last").getValue();
            pass = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this, "Database Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newPassword();
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void newPassword(){

    ...
    user = new User(first, last, email, contact, pass, username, address);
    db.child("users").child(username).setValue(user);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Change successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TabMenu.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Every time I start this activity, it will give the error immediately on the `onCancelled(DatabaseError){Toast.makeText(..., "Database Error", ...).show();}`

Comment: All the text inputs make it hard to see what the problem is. Can you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values for `username`?

Comment: At first glance this looks suspicious: ` if(username.matches(ds.getKey())){`. Did you mean to use `username.equals(ds.getKey)`?

Comment: Those if-else statements where only to check if the EditText has value, after changing the .matches to .equals, the program would stopped.

Comment: after some debugging, program won't stop but password won't change

Comment: In that case, please reproduce the problem with hard-coded values and update the code in your question. It'll make it much easier to help, which in turn improves the change that we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare two Strings in Java, you need to use `equals` method and not `matches`.

[matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

An invocation of this method of the form str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the expression

java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, str).

So change this line of code:

```
username.matches(ds.getKey())
```

with

```
username.equals(ds.getKey())
```

To change the password, you only need to use `setValue()` method directly on the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("users").child("brian").child("password").setValue("newPassword");
```

Comment: still, no, program would eventually stopped.

Comment: after some debug, program won't stop but the password won't change

Comment: Still it didn't worked. The rule that I set to my database is the default one, but auth == null, so I didn't do some authentication. I'm sharing this maybe it could help.

Comment: I added .addValueEventListener on the onCreate(). The override onCancelled(DatabaseError) would give me the message that I set for the error before I could add values to the database. I didn't put in the listener the db.child("users").("brian").setValues("values"); I putted it in the listener of the button.

Comment: You don't need a listener in order to change a value in your Firebase database. You only need to use setValue() directly on the reference. The correct way is this: `db.child("users").("brian").child("password").setValues("values");`

Comment: Move all lines of code from `newPassword()` method inside the `onDataChange` method and make all the declaration like this `String username = (String)dataSnapshot.child(userText.getText().toString().trim()).child("username").getValue();` Don't make them global.

Comment: Still it will give error on the onCancelled(DatabaseError){}

Comment: Making both changes?